# IP address to Domain Name? DNS?

Tags: dns, ip, domain-name

I'm trying to find the authoritative name servers for a given IP address and as far as I can see the only way to find the name servers is by using the domain name of the IP.

1. How do I convert the IP to domain name (not hostname)?
2. Or how do I find the authoritative name servers for any IP address?

Comment: As asked, your question doesn't really make any sense. There is no such thing as "the authoritative name servers for a given IP address". There can be name servers authoritative for an IP address's reverse lookup address, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dig to get PTR RR, for example:

```
dig -x 8.8.8.8
```